# Reversing a string in python (WORD by WORD)

Tags: python-2.7

How about reversing a string, not by each character but by word.
Like for example: "Python is the best programming language",  the output should be "language programming best the is Python", but the problem is that there shouldn't be any predefined function included.

Comment: Str.split() will give you list of words from your string. You can then reverse a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With split:

```
x = "Python is the best programming language"
x.split()[::-1]

Out [2]: ['language', 'programming', 'best', 'the', 'is', 'Python']
```

Without split or any f(x):

```
l = []
length = 0
string = ''
for i in x:
    length+=1
for i in x:
    length -= 1
    if i != " " and i!="\n":
        string += i
    else:
        l[:0] += [string]
        string = ''
    if length == 0:
        l[:0] += [string]
        string = ''

In: [3]     print l
Out: [4]    ['language', 'programming', 'best', 'the', 'is', 'Python']
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there any possibilities that len() should be use instead of split() ?

def reverse(text):
    if len(text) <= 1:
        return text

    return reverse(text[1:]) + text[0]

This works but it reverses all character.

Comment: @HannahEraDolendo Not without looping twice regarding pre-existing functions? I am not sure. See my edit. You don't need to use len(), that's the power of index slicing in Python. :)

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the way you want you have to first create a list and then reverse the list and then rejoin back that list

```
sentence = "Python is cool"
list = sentence.split()
print " ".join(list[::-1])
```

Comment: Thank you! This one works but I need to refactor it because we're not allowed to use .split(). :(

Answer (score 0):

my_string="Today is Tuesday"

"".join(reverse(my_string))

and

my_string[::-1]

both will give the required reverse string